# Why big corporations do not include the copyright notice into their WEB [HTML] code?

Tags: copyright, corporate-law, copyright-notice

One of the first things that I learned when writing code was to copyright it. As far as I know, the things to do are:

1. Create a license file that describes the copyright and lists the
   software files.
2. Add the copyright to each file containing code. Ex: `# (C) Copyright <years> <name>. <license>.`
3. [Optional] Register the software into official organizations of intellectual property.

the stages 1) and 2) I've always seen it in heavy client software, but I ignore why big corporations like Facebook, Google, Microsoft, etc... never do it in their web code (speaking about step 2). And they also don't even use the HTML meta tags:

```
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="copyright" content="">
```

Is there any legal reason behind this? Is their code already declared on step 3 so they don't bother doing step 2?

Answer (score 2):

### One of the first things you learned was wrong

Or, at least, incomplete.

Copyright exists the instant the literary or artistic work is "fixed": that is, recorded in some manner that is retrievable and reproducible. Under the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), a requirement in domestic law that a work is registered or marked with a copyright notice is not allowed.